# How to pass value to Input KnockoutJS attr via xml

Tags: magento2, checkout, xml, knockoutjs

We are trying to pass `placeholder` value to `input` element via xml files. So far, the only solution we've found was modifying `input.html` from:

```
<input data-bind="(...)
attr: {
    (...)
    placeholder: placeholder,
    (...)
}" />
```

to

```
<input data-bind="(...)
attr: {
    (...)
    placeholder: tooltip.placeholder,
    (...)
}" />
```

and passing our argument inside `checkout_index_index.xml` with:

```
<item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
    (...)
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="description" xsi:type="string" translate="true">For delivery questions.</item>
            <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string">Some text</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

But this is the least elegant solution We could think of. 
Can you please tell us the proper, elegant way to pass `<item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string">Some text</item>` to `input.html`?

Our best guess is, that, somehow `<item name="placeholder"(...)` is checked/validated before adding to `#checkout` JSON and thus it's not appearing in it (We've checked it, assigned `placeholder` value won't appear there).

P.S.
We're aware about `"placeholder: label"` ""fix"", but this is even less elegant way than ours, as We'd like to keep templates intact and iteract with xmls only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, yes, I've managed to enable passing `placeholder` via `xml`.

Solution is [overriding methods of](https://webkul.com/blog/overriding-rewriting-classes-magento2/) `AttributeMerger.php` :

- `getFieldConfig`
- `getMultilineFieldConfig`.

Each of these methods have `$additionalConfig` passed, which is, from description:

`* @param array $additionalConfig field configuration provided via layout XML`

So you just need to add following value with key:

```
'placeholder' => isset($additionalConfig['placeholder'])
    ? $additionalConfig['placeholder']
    : '',
```

to:

- `$element=[(...)]` array in `getFieldConfig`
- `$line=[(...)]` array in `getMultilineFieldConfig`.

You can replace `''` with some default placeholder value, I used `$attributeConfig['label'] . '*'`.

**The only problem here is, that solution won't work with hidden inputs (like region input after changing country from US). If someone could provide workaround for this case it would be great.**

Exemplary `AttributeMerger.php` inside custom `Checkout` module:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Light4website\Checkout\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Directory\Helper\Data as DirectoryHelper;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface as CustomerRepository;

class AttributeMerger extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger
{
protected function getFieldConfig(
    $attributeCode,
    array $attributeConfig,
    array $additionalConfig,
    $providerName,
    $dataScopePrefix
) {
    // street attribute is unique in terms of configuration, so it has its own configuration builder
    if (isset($attributeConfig['validation']['input_validation'])) {
        $validationRule = $attributeConfig['validation']['input_validation'];
        $attributeConfig['validation'][$this->inputValidationMap[$validationRule]] = true;
        unset($attributeConfig['validation']['input_validation']);
    }

    if ($attributeConfig['formElement'] == 'multiline') {
        return $this->getMultilineFieldConfig($attributeCode, $attributeConfig, $providerName, $dataScopePrefix);
    }

    $uiComponent = isset($this->formElementMap[$attributeConfig['formElement']])
        ? $this->formElementMap[$attributeConfig['formElement']]
        : 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract';
    $elementTemplate = isset($this->templateMap[$attributeConfig['formElement']])
        ? 'ui/form/element/' . $this->templateMap[$attributeConfig['formElement']]
        : 'ui/form/element/' . $attributeConfig['formElement'];

    $element = [
        'component' => isset($additionalConfig['component']) ? $additionalConfig['component'] : $uiComponent,
        'config' => [
            // customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)
            'customScope' => $dataScopePrefix,
            'customEntry' => isset($additionalConfig['config']['customEntry'])
                ? $additionalConfig['config']['customEntry']
                : null,
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => isset($additionalConfig['config']['elementTmpl'])
                ? $additionalConfig['config']['elementTmpl']
                : $elementTemplate,
            'tooltip' => isset($additionalConfig['config']['tooltip'])
                ? $additionalConfig['config']['tooltip']
                : null,
        ],
        'dataScope' => $dataScopePrefix . '.' . $attributeCode,
        'label' => $attributeConfig['label'],
        'placeholder' => isset($additionalConfig['placeholder'])
            ? $additionalConfig['placeholder']
            : $attributeConfig['label'] . '*',
        'provider' => $providerName,
        'sortOrder' => isset($additionalConfig['sortOrder'])
            ? $additionalConfig['sortOrder']
            : $attributeConfig['sortOrder'],
        'validation' => $this->mergeConfigurationNode('validation', $additionalConfig, $attributeConfig),
        'options' => $this->getFieldOptions($attributeCode, $attributeConfig),
        'filterBy' => isset($additionalConfig['filterBy']) ? $additionalConfig['filterBy'] : null,
        'customEntry' => isset($additionalConfig['customEntry']) ? $additionalConfig['customEntry'] : null,
        'visible' => isset($additionalConfig['visible']) ? $additionalConfig['visible'] : true,
    ];

    if (isset($attributeConfig['value']) && $attributeConfig['value'] != null) {
        $element['value'] = $attributeConfig['value'];
    } elseif (isset($attributeConfig['default']) && $attributeConfig['default'] != null) {
        $element['value'] = $attributeConfig['default'];
    } else {
        $defaultValue = $this->getDefaultValue($attributeCode);
        if (null !== $defaultValue) {
            $element['value'] = $defaultValue;
        }
    }
    return $element;
}

protected function getMultilineFieldConfig($attributeCode, array $attributeConfig, $providerName, $dataScopePrefix)
{
    $lines = [];
    unset($attributeConfig['validation']['required-entry']);
    for ($lineIndex = 0; $lineIndex < (int)$attributeConfig['size']; $lineIndex++) {
        $isFirstLine = $lineIndex === 0;
        $line = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                // customScope is used to group elements within a single form e.g. they can be validated separately
                'customScope' => $dataScopePrefix,
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
            ],
            'dataScope' => $lineIndex,
            'provider' => $providerName,
            'validation' => $isFirstLine
                ? array_merge(
                    ['required-entry' => (bool)$attributeConfig['required']],
                    $attributeConfig['validation']
                )
                : $attributeConfig['validation'],
            'additionalClasses' => $isFirstLine ? : 'additional',
            'placeholder' => isset($additionalConfig['placeholder'])
                ? $additionalConfig['placeholder']
                : $attributeConfig['label'] . '*',
        ];
        if ($isFirstLine && isset($attributeConfig['default']) && $attributeConfig['default'] != null) {
            $line['value'] = $attributeConfig['default'];
        }
        $lines[] = $line;
    }
    return [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
        'label' => $attributeConfig['label'],
        'required' => (bool)$attributeConfig['required'],
        'dataScope' => $dataScopePrefix . '.' . $attributeCode,
        'provider' => $providerName,
        'sortOrder' => $attributeConfig['sortOrder'],
        'type' => 'group',
        'config' => [
            'template' => 'ui/group/group',
            'additionalClasses' => $attributeCode,
        ],
        'children' => $lines,
    ];
}
}
```